# Where is my Directory holding MS fonts?

Tags: fonts

Here is the steps to install ms fonts.

```
apt-get install  ttf-mscorefonts-installer
dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

There is a window  pop  up.

[image]

How to fill the blank to continue?
Os tell me do the job.
At the end of outout for `apt-get install  ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

```
All done, no errors.
The following fonts failed to install :  andale32.exe comic32.exe.
The fonts are NOT installed.
Please run 'dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer' to perform the installation again
```

Comment: Why are you reconfiguring it after you install it? It's already configured during the installation.

Comment: Perhaps: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` ?

Comment: On my box I have them in the folder `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts`. Don't remember how it was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

(automatic approve license agreement)